# Using true and false in macros in C99

Tags: c, boolean, c-preprocessor, c99, preprocessor-directive

I am writing some code using a customized gcc compiler that supports a subset of C99. Using compiler options I defined a macro like this:

```
ENABLE_LOGGING=true
```

I am using it in my code like this:

```
#if ENABLE_LOGGING
#define LOG(foo) { log(foo); }
#else
#define LOG(foo)
#endif
```

It just turned out that this doesn't work reliably. Sometimes the `LOG` containing code is used, sometimes the emtpy `LOG` is used (same project, same compiler setting).

When changing the macro argument to:

```
ENABLE_LOGGING=1
```

everything works.

I understand that `true` could be unknown to the preprocessor. But then, why does it work most times? And why do I get no warning or error during compilation for the modules where it doesn't work?

Comment: `ENABLE_LOGGING=true` is not a valid C macro declaration. Did you mean `#define ENABLE_LOGGING true` or something else?

Comment: I defined it using compiler options not using code. The above is the format used for compiler options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#define hehe true
#if hehe
#error hehe
#else
#error haha
#endif
```

will `#error haha` because `hehe` expands to `true` and `true` will be substitued by a `0` because

> **§6.10.1¶4** all remaining identifiers (including those lexically
>       identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number ***0***

But if you happen to `#include <stdbool.h>` before your `#if`, it will `#error hehe`, because

> **§7.18** The header  defines four macros. …
>
> **¶3** The remaining three macros are *suitable for use in #if preprocessing
>   directives*. They are `true` which expands to the integer constant
>   ***1*** …